# assigning value to array instead of function parameter

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];

var fun  = function(arr){
 var arr2 = [4,5,6];
arr = arr.concat(arr2)
}

fun(arr1)
console.log(arr1)
```

I am passing `arr1` into my `fun()` function. After `fun()` does its work, `arr1` should look like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, but instead it's `[1,2,3]`. It seems that when I do `arr = arr.concat(arr2)` I am basically reassigning the value of the parameter in my function, not `arr1`. How can I get around this issue so that I get the desirable outcome?

Comment: return is all i needed to do. Thanks @Pointy for pointing me to the resource!